# Does Facebook Analytics Have Offline Capability?

Tags: facebook-analytics

Does Facebook Analytics register events that are sent offline, or misses them?

For example, Firebase and GameAnalytics have such capability. They store events and when the device connects to internet, they sent all together.

If there is no such feature in Facebook Analytics, are there any workarounds to sent offline events to Facebook?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the Mobile SDK used to log events for FB Analytics stores events until and forwards when connected.